# Why use sine and cosine to find the components of a vector?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, vectors

Why use sine and cosine to find the components of a vector? To find the cosine and sine, the point must not belong to the circumference and it must be giometric? So why do we use sine and cosine?
Do you have an in-depth guide so you can study mechanics, electromagnetism, optics .... quickly?

Comment: What do you mean? We use cos & sin *precisely* because they're the x & y coordinates of a point on the unit circle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#Trigonometric_functions_on_the_unit_circle

Comment: https://www.dummies.com/education/science/physics/how-to-find-vector-components/

Comment: What may help: while we tend to think of sine and cosine as properties of a circle, they are actually properties of a triangle.  It just so happens that if you look at all possible triangles with a hypothenuse of 1, they trace out a circle.  In the world of vectors, its the triangle that mattered.

Comment: It seems you want to understand physics quickly, but you haven't understood basic planar geometry. You gotta start simple, then build up to the more complicated things. Trigonometric functions are really just ratios of lengths of triangles. Please explore here https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-interactive-unit-circle.html Furthermore, if you want to "quickly" understand something in physics maybe check out the Schaum's series https://vinaire.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/schaum-beginning-physics-i.pdf

Comment: A better question: why do you question the standard method of resolving the components of a vector?  The math behind vector resolution is several HUNDRED years old.

Comment: Please frame the problem for us. What situation are you talking about here. Application of trigonometric functions is widespread so we don't understand in which particular situation you are inquiring about.

Answer (score 1):

By the mathematical definition of a vector, it can be resolved as the addition of constituent vectors using trigonometry. Using a Cartesian coordinate system, we want to know the components of the vector along each of the three orthogonal axes and for that the trigonometric functions are used to resolve the vector along the axes.  The resolved components add according to the addition property of vectors to form the original vector.  For example for an artillery shell we want to know the distance travelled in both the vertical and horizontal directions. In two dimensions sin and cos are used, in three dimensions direction cosines are useful.  See any text on Vector Analysis, I like those by Harry Davis.

In physics we use free vectors, defined only by magnitude and direction (but the location of the vector determines its effect).  This is important for translating among different Cartesian coordinate systems; for example, to consider motion in a non-inertial reference frame in translation and rotation with respect to an inertial frame.  The vector is the same in both systems; its components along the systems axes are not the same, and the time derivative of the vector is different between the two systems.  See any physics Mechanics test.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec c=\vec a + \vec b$ and $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are at right angles to each other then the vectors  $\vec a, \vec b,\vec c$ form a right angled triangle. From the properties of right angled triangles we know that if the angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec c$ is $\theta$ then

$|\vec a|=|\vec c|\cos \theta
\\|\vec b|=|\vec c|\sin \theta$